# Access to the elements with row number greater than the row number of element

Tags: matlab

I have a 3x3 array, called q, for example:

```
q=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]
u=one of the element in array q
[row,col]=find(q==u)     % to find the row and column number of element u
```

how to access the elements with row number greater than the row number of element u?
i really appreciate the help, if someone can share the ideas.

Comment: you mean `q(row+1,col)`?

Comment: I think he means `q(row+1:end,:)`

Comment: @Adiel that is the answer he's asking, you should post it as answer.

Comment: @SamuelNLP I doubt if it's a typical question, that people will search and will happy to find the answer. Consider that it's so little "answer", I didn't think that it deserve to state as an answer...